# form check box value retain if form having 1 or more error

Tags: php, forms

$facility=$_POST['interests'];

```
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="" value="wifi" value="<?php echo in_array('wifi', $facility)??>checked='checked'<?php:;?>" /><label class="check_label">Wifi</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="" value="spa"  value="<?php echo in_array('spa', $facility)?>checked='checked'<?php:;?>"/><label class="check_label">Spa</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="" value="pet allowed" value="<?php echo in_array('pet allowed', $facility)?>checked='checked'<?php:;?>"/><label class="check_label">Pet Allowed</label>
```

second method:-

```
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="" value="wifi" value="<?php  in_array('wifi', $facility){?>checked='checked'<?php}?>" /><label class="check_label">Wifi</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="" value="spa"  value="<?php  in_array('spa', $facility){?>checked='checked'<?php}?>"/><label class="check_label">Spa</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="" value="pet allowed" value="<?php  in_array('pet allowed', $facility){?>checked='checked'<?php}?>"/><label class="check_label">Pet Allowed</label>
```

i apply both method in order retain the post value in form if user make any mistake.if he made mistake checkbox remain check after submit but it not working.

Comment: i'm sorry i was frustrated in solving this issue but it is correct in original script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### finally i fixed the bug

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="" value="wifi" <?php if(in_array('wifi', $facility)==TRUE){echo "value=wifi checked='checked'";}?> /><label class="check_label">Wifi</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="" value="spa"  <?php if(in_array('wifi', $facility)==TRUE){echo "value=spa checked='checked'";}?>/><label class="check_label">Spa</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" id="" value="pet allowed" <?php if(in_array('wifi', $facility)==TRUE){echo "value=pet allowed checked='checked'";}?>/><label class="check_label">Pet Allowed</label>
```

previously script which i used logical incorrect:-

```
<?php  
  in_array('wifi', $facility){
?> checked='checked'
<?php}?>" //there is no if else exist how it check condition is true or false
```

now i change that script and using conditions:-

```
<?php 
      if(in_array('wifi', $facility)==TRUE){
         echo "value=wifi checked='checked'";
      }
?>
```

Comment: You should specify what was the issue